# GKE public cluster with NAT getaway - Is there any possibility to use NAT getaway with particular API base or pod base

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nat

I am using public cluster, I have done IP-MASQ to use cloud NAT getaway. Is it possible to apply the NAT getaway for specific service or API calls or particular pod

I am trying to achieve the NAT getaway for specific customer, to egress from our end will use static NAT getaway. NAT actually apply for entire cluster. however I need to specify on particular service or API calls or on Particular POD

Answer (score 0):

Seem this is impossible, a Cloud NAT need to attach a Cloud Route and a VPC. In your case, I think you can use with an HTTP proxy (HTTP_PROXY).